In term of quality of reconstructed data (Images) which one in more efficient Transformer or Autoencoder?
I am working on wireless communication and resource management, where IoT devices collect data from the environments and send it to the servers. Through this work, we aim to send only semantic data instead of raw data to the server. If we consider the Transformer and Autoencoder, which is more efficient if we consider the quality of reconstructed data if we consider images as raw data?
I tried Autoencoder and expect that Transformer more effifient, I need yours feedback
